# List or not a bad experience in a resume

Tags: resume, career-development, work-experience

I would like to get more help on my question where I cannot get a clear view.

I worked for company A (very good and large company) on a project for 2 years (with a 2-year contract, until Dec 2016). Terminated the contract (and the project) I found, on time, company B (start-up) that I joined in January 2017.

The experience with B was terrible, very unorganized, people were getting fired every-day. The last week of my probation period (5 months) the internal HR offered me to extend my probation signing a "mutual termination" for the next 4 months (I was basically signing to resign). 
I declined, saying "no" and then she told me "ok, then we fire you" I said: "ok, I do not want to stay here one more minute". I then got fired. (June 2017).

In September my old company A, knowing I lost my job, called me again for another 2-year project (where I am working at the moment).

I do not know what to do with the bad experience with company B in my resume. Would you list the experience? I would like to avoid it.

Basically, in the 3 months of unemployment I starting learning a new language, so I could extend the 3 months to 9 months.

So this is how it looks now:

September 2017 - today: Company A
January 2017 - June 2017: Company B (the bad experience)
Dec 2014 - Dec 2016: Company A

What I would like to list:

September 2017 - today: Company A
Dec 2014 - Dec 2016: Company A

This gives me a gap of 9 months to fill, and the options are: 
 - Learning a new language, or 
 - I took a break before starting a new project (since it is the same company).

Would you list or hide the experience with company B?

Comment: I got confused on who is Company A and who is Company B... mind clarifying?

Comment: I modified the question to make it more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Leave it in there. They will ask why it is so short.

This is your chance to explain it maturely. Anyone could have a bad work experience, how you deal with it will impress them.

Explain what lessons you learned, even if the job was short. A short painful experience can be very educational. It will also impress them if you are able to highlight the good things about the job, it will show that you are reasonable and not a negative person.

Comment: Indeed, such "big" gap (9 months) surely will be noticed. It's better not to lie about it and be honest on the experience. Also, great first answer :o